# MVC-Create a ViewModel class instance from the urlreferrer url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given:

```
request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath = "/MyApp/MyHome/List";
```

and I have a Route Mapping that handles this where MyHome is my controller and List is an action that takes a ViewModel. Other variations of this Route include paging and sorting but these are captured by the ViewModel.

My question is this:

How can I use the above URL to generate an instance of the related ViewModel?

**EDIT:** I have an JQuery Dialog that is adding/updating/deleting an item in a list that is shown by the url in the urlreferrer- the example given is the most basic. When the dialog sends the data to be a/u/d, I want to return the updated body of the list and display that. This information is handled by a different ViewModel than what is instantiated on the POST from the dialog (the url posted to is "/MyApp/MyHome/Edit/True" - for creating a new whatever). This piece follows the standard MVC process and of course works. What I want to do is create a *second* ViewModel based on the ViewModel for the list action and return this as a partial view containing the updated paged list.

Comment: Could you provide a little more details?  You want to dynamically create the model, or is this you create different view models based on the URL, or what?

Comment: I've been thinking I wasn't as clear as I should have been. I'll edit the above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I think I have this figured out. This is not pretty but it works. I welcome anybody's input to actually feed this through a ModelBinder or any other MVC artifact but here's what I came up with:

First we need to fake a request using the UrlReferrer instead of the actual url being requested:

```
public class FakeHttpContext : HttpContextBase
 {
      public FakeHttpContext(HttpContextBase currentContext)
      {
           _request = new FakeHttpRequest(currentContext.Request);
      }

      HttpRequestBase _request;
      public override HttpRequestBase Request
      {
           get
           {
                return _request;
           }
      }

      HttpResponseBase _response = new FakeHttpResponse();
      public override HttpResponseBase Response
      {
           get
           {
                return _response;
           }
      }

      class FakeHttpRequest : HttpRequestBase
      {
           HttpRequestBase _request;

           public FakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestBase currentRequest)
           {
                if(currentRequest == null)
                     throw new ArgumentNullException();

                this._request = currentRequest;
           }

           public override string ApplicationPath
           {
                get
                {
                     return this._request.ApplicationPath;
                }
           }

           public override string AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
           {
                get
                {
                     return "~" + this._request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.Remove(0, this._request.ApplicationPath.Length);
                }
           }

           public override string PathInfo
           {
                get
                {
                     return this._request.PathInfo;
                }
           }

      }

      class FakeHttpResponse : HttpResponseBase
      {
      }
 }
```

Next, we feed the fake call through the RouteTable to get it broken down. and match up properties to the RouteData.Values.

```
public static class RouteAndModelBinder
 {
      public static void BuildViewModel<TViewModel>(ControllerContext context, TViewModel model)
      {
           FakeHttpContext fake = new FakeHttpContext(context.HttpContext);
           RouteData test = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(fake);

           PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TViewModel).GetProperties();

           string value;

           foreach(PropertyInfo info in properties)
           {
                if(test.Values.ContainsKey(info.Name))
                {
                     value = (string)test.Values[info.Name];

                     if(value == null)
                     {
                          continue;
                     }

                     if(info.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                          info.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                     {
                          Type[] nullables = info.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();

                          if(nullables.Length > 0)
                          {
                               Type nullableType = nullables[0];

                               if(nullableType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                               {
                                    object o = Enum.Parse(nullableType, value);
                                    info.SetValue(model, o, null);
                               }
                               else if(nullableType == typeof(Int32))
                               {
                                    info.SetValue(model, int.Parse(value), null);

                               }
                               else
                               {
                                    info.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(value, info.PropertyType), null);
                               }
                          }

                     }
                     else
                     {
                          if(info.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                          {
                               object o = Enum.Parse(info.PropertyType.BaseType, value);
                               info.SetValue(model, o, null);
                          }
                          else if(info.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                          {
                               info.SetValue(model, int.Parse(value), null);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                               info.SetValue(model, value, null);
                          }

                     }
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Again, I welcome anybody's suggestions on how I can do this with already established MVC code (ie, ModelBinders, etc). I took some ideas and probably code from [here](http://juztinwilzon.blogspot.com/2006/10/setting-nullable-enum-through.html)  (for the nullable type) and [here](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/url-generation-in-asp-net-mvc-without-httpcontext).